# Magento2.4 - How to add New Link in Mini Cart Popup?

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, magento2.4.3, magento2minicart

I want add some New Link in `Mini Cart Popup`,like below image,

[image]

How can I add this links?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Simply copy **minicart.phtml** from below path

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/minicart.phtml

and put in your theme as on below path and add your links in that file

> app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_checkout/templates/minicart.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `minicart.phtml` file using below code inside your custom module's default.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" template="Vendor_Module::cart/minicart.phtml"  after="logo"/>   
    </body>
</page>
```

**NOTE: Change Vendor_Module with your custom module name**

Then create minicart.phtml inside view/frontend/templates/minicart.phtml

add your links inside this file using html